# Why add 1 to the lower bound in binary search?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

A binary search implementation is as follows:

```
binary_search(A, target):
   lo = 1, hi = size(A)
   while lo <= hi:
      mid = lo + (hi-lo)/2
      if A[mid] == target:
         return mid            
      else if A[mid] < target: 
         lo = mid+1
      else:
         hi = mid-1
```

Can 
             lo = mid+1

Be replaced with

```
         lo = mid
```

And Can 
             hi = mid-1

Be replaced with

```
         hi = mid
```

I don't get the point of this ones. If anyone could shed some light -- that would be useful.

Comment: `mid` represents the index of the element you are currently testing. Adding and subtracting 1 ensures that you don't re-evaluate that element.

Comment: What if we skip over the value we're looking for?

Comment: You won't, try writing out an example by hand to verify

Answer (score -1):

When you have seen in the first `if` that A[mid] is not the target, then you know that mid element certainly can be skipped without affecting the correctness.

So yes, lo and hi can be set to mid for the next iteration, but then you would only be considering one extra element, which you know for sure isn't the value that you are searching for.

The run time complexity of O(Log n) will be unaffected.